# Definition of multivariate regression coefficient

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, covariance, multivariate-regression

I know that the regression coefficient of $Y$ and $X$ is defined as

$$\beta(Y,X) = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)}{\mathrm{Var}(X)}$$

Does this expression also hold in a multivariate regression with $Y$, $X$ and $Z$ as additional explanatory variable?

Comment: Thank you -A. I also figured that the above definition must be wrong in a multivariate setting. However, how can I conveniently express beta(i) as a function of sample moments?

Comment: If you have one response (dependent variable) Y your question is more simply posed as being about multiple regression. Please read the tags for multiple regression and multivariate regression to see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the multivariate setting a vector of regression coefficients are defined as:

$$\beta=(X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$$

Each element in the beta vector depends on the cross-covariances in the matrix of cross-products $X^TX$.

You can think that each coefficient is a kind of partial correlation coefficient where coefficient measures marginal effect on the target variable when effects of other variables in the r.h.s are taken into account. But do not extrapolate very far away from the range of mutual variation... :)